# Wordpress $wpdb mysqli_prepare statements

Tags: php, mysqli, wordpress

I am trying to convert a website to use the $wpdb functionality and can't for the life of me figure out how to actually create a prepared statement that I can bind to and execute. The WP prepare statement only sanitizes the values it actually does nothing near a actual prepare. This seems extremely unproductive and just dumb am I missing something? Does anyone know if there is a way to get a hold of the underlying mysqli functionality from the $wpdb?

I have tried without much success:

```
$stmt = $wpdb->mysqli_prepare($wpdb, $sql);
```

Hoping to use the "Magic Methods" to get ahold of the mysqli stuff. Anyone have any ideas?

What I am after is [MySql Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [MySql Bind Param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) most importantly. For example something like:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /*** Most Important what I am after ***/
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

What I am not able to do is figure out a way to be able to bind variables since WP does not actually create a mysqli prepared statement. Using prepared statments like this enables me to be able to put all the changes/updates/deletes into basically one Read/Write to the MySql server not executing one query for every change. If I can get ahold of the native smtp object from the $wpdb I could do what I need.

Comment: Did you `global $wpdb` first? Typically Wordpress uses prepare like `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query))`

Comment: Yeah I always use the global WordPress Database. The problem is the WP prepare is not a real prepare it only "Sanitizes" the query to prevent injection. See my original question for what I am after.

Comment: It might help attract answers if you could give a full example of what code you're trying to run, and say exactly what it's not doing that you expect it to do. You're right in what you're assuming about the difference between actual prepared statements and wpdb's prepare, though, as is summarised in one of the answers to [this very similar question on wp.se](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20476/does-wpdb-prepare-not-create-a-prepared-statement-that-i-can-execute-multiple)...

Comment: I'm not sure how to use $wpdb to do a real php `prepare`, but you could always extend the `wpdb` class and create your own prepare method using php's `prepare`. Other than that, Wordpress uses its `prepare` method to bind params like $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(SELECT ..., $bind1, $bind2 ) )

Comment: @TimHallman Yeah that's exactly what I am trying not to do. I am developing a "Plugin" and wanted to keep it as a total plug n play application without having to change anything, so it would run on a default WP installation. Thank you though I am sure there is a way to do this.

Comment: You could easily extend the `wpdb` class from within your plugin.